# How to check duplicate entry in multiple select?

Tags: jquery, yii2, multi-select

I am using Yii advanced framework.
In case of add value in `multiselect` it takes duplicate records.
How to prevent this issue?

```
<?php if($product_attribute->isNewRecord){?>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="attrmngmnt" name="attrcom[]" multiple="multiple">                   
      </select>          
<?php } else { ?>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="attrmngmnt" name="attrcom[]" multiple="multiple">
         <?php foreach ($data as $key => $eachdata) { ?>          
             <option value1="<?php echo $eachdata['id_attribute_group']?>" value="<?php echo $eachdata['id_attribute']?>" selected="selected"> 
             <?php echo $eachdata['attribute_group_name'].' : '.$eachdata['attribute_name']; ?>
             </option>  
         <?php } ?>
      </select>   
<?php }?>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
<?php   
$url = \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['product/combinationform']);

  $this->registerJs( 

    "$('#add_attr').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();    
        var attr = $('#attribute-id_attribute_group :selected').text();        
        $('.form-group_select').show();        

      var duplicate=false;
        var attr1 = $('#title :selected').text();
        var attrval1 = $('#attribute-id_attribute_group :selected').val();
        var attrval = $('#title :selected').val();                

        $('#attrmngmnt').append($('<option>', { 
            value1: attrval1,
            value: attrval,            
            text : attr + ' : ' + attr1,
        }));

      $('#attrmngmnt option').attr('selected', 'selected')

    });"
  ); 
?>
```

Please help me how to fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in your `$data array` to remove duplicate values.

```
<?php if($product_attribute->isNewRecord){?>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="attrmngmnt" name="attrcom[]" multiple="multiple">                   
      </select>          
<?php } else { ?>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="attrmngmnt" name="attrcom[]" multiple="multiple">
         <?php foreach (array_unique($data) as $key => $eachdata) { ?>          
             <option value1="<?php echo $eachdata['id_attribute_group']?>" value="<?php echo $eachdata['id_attribute']?>" selected="selected"> 
             <?php echo $eachdata['attribute_group_name'].' : '.$eachdata['attribute_name']; ?>
             </option>  
         <?php } ?>
      </select>   
<?php }?>
```